# Python: How can I populate rows between dates for each ID?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, date

**Objective:** I want to plot out the current and leaving members each month.

So I have two dataframes (see below): **Dataframe A** has an ID, date they joined the club, and dates YTD as a row. **Dataframe B** has a start date, end date and membership type for each ID.

I want to populate **Dataframe A** with new columns showing the membership type and active and terminated flags.

Conceptually, I'm not even sure how to approach this on Python, **Excel**, and even SQL. If it was for one event and one ID, I can simply create a mask on Python. But I'm not sure how to loop this would work between dataframes. Any suggestions?

**Dataframe A**

| ID | Date | Created Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2001-03-01 | 2001-03-01 |
| 123 | 2001-04-01 | 2001-03-01 |
| 123 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-03-01 |
| 123 | 2001-06-01 | 2001-03-01 |
| 456 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-05-01 |
| 456 | 2001-06-01 | 2001-05-01 |

**Dataframe B**

| ID | Start Date | End Date | Membership |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2001-03-01 | 2001-04-30 | Bronze |
| 123 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-01 | Iron |
| 456 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-30 | Gold |

**Desired Output**

| ID | Date | Join Date | Leave Date | Active | Termination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2001-03-01 | 2001-03-05 | 2001-06-30 | 1 |  |
| 123 | 2001-04-01 | 2001-03-05 | 2001-06-30 | 1 |  |
| 123 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-03-05 | 2001-06-30 | 1 |  |
| 123 | 2001-06-01 | 2001-03-05 | 2001-06-30 |  | 1 |
| 456 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-30 | 1 |  |
| 456 | 2001-06-01 | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-30 |  | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

First, you should ensure all the dates needed is in datetime format.

Next, get the join date and leave date for unique ID.

Merge them together and create columns then filter with the condition.

Sample code:

```
df_a["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_a["Date"], errors = 'coerce')
df_b["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_b["Start Date"], errors = 'coerce')
df_b["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_b["End Date"], errors = 'coerce')

df_join = df_a.groupby(by="ID", as_index=False).agg({"Start Date": "min"}).rename(columns={"Start Date": "Join Date"}, inplace=True)
df_leave = df_b.groupby(by="ID", as_index=False).agg({"End Date": "min"}).rename(columns={"End Date": "Leave Date"}, inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(df_a, df_join, on="ID", how="left")
df = pd.merge(df, df_leave, on="ID", how="left")

df["Active"] = (df["Date"].dt.to_period('M') < df["Leave Date"].dt.to_period('M'))
df["Termination"] = (df["Date"].dt.to_period('M') >= df["Leave Date"].dt.to_period('M'))
```

This answer will be in boolean format. if you want to be in numeric format

```
df.loc[df["Active"] == True, "Active"] = 1
df.loc[df["Termination"] == True, "Termination"] = 1
```